# Do primitives need to be initialized to zero?

Tags: objective-c, initialization, primitive

Do I need to explicitly zero primitives, i.e., set `BOOL`s to `NO`, set `int`s to `0`?

Do I need to explicitly assign an `NSString*` to `nil` or `@""`?

I know that pointers must be explicitly set to `nil`, otherwise they may be filled with garbage. (Or is that only for Objective-C++?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what kind of variable you're talking about. Globals, static variables and instance variables are already guaranteed to be initialized to 0.

Local variables are a different story. They are never initialized *at all* by default, so you shouldn't read their values until you initialize or set them. It isn't strictly necessary to initialize them to 0 specifically. For example, the following code is very redundant:

```
Controller *controller = nil;
int countOfThings = 0;
controller = [Controller sharedInstance];
countOfThings = controller.totalThings - controller.thingsUsed;
```

Instead, you should initialize variables to the values you actually want:

```
Controller *controller = [Controller sharedInstance];
int countOfThings = controller.totalThings - controller.thingsUsed;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's always good programming practice to initialize primitives, but in general it's only required if you're referring to that variable when there's a chance it wasn't set to anything except garbage memory.

I believe the compiler still throws warnings on "uninitialized variables", but if not, there's definitely a compiler checkbox in XCode for that.

The [compiler flag for this](http://www.noxeos.com/2011/02/04/xcode-build-settings/) is `-Wuninitialized`, b.t.w.